# pyzmq Segmentation fault on large .recv()

Tags: pyzmq

- edited - I think I wrongly pointed the blame at pyzmq - I actually was running in a QThread and upon suggestion worked on a full working example - not using QThread and I do not see any issues.  I'm going to drop my working example for anyone who may want to reference this example.

I'm attempting to publish data on a **`pyzmq`** socket.  I have experience here but never for larger data. On occasion, I'm getting a seg fault or at other times a message about **`free()`**.  This happens more often for larger data sets, up to a point where it never actually works (depending on size).

subscriber code:

```
import zmq
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

class ZmqListener(Thread):
    def __init__(self, addr, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.addr = addr
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        socket = zmq.Context().socket(zmq.SUB)
        socket.connect("tcp://%s:%s" % (self.addr, self.port))
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "test:".encode('utf-8'))
        poller = zmq.Poller()
        poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            print(socket.recv())
            s = dict(poller.poll(1000))
            if s:
                if s.get(socket) == zmq.POLLIN:
                    msg = socket.recv()
                    print(msg)
        socket.close()

th = ZmqListener('localhost', IMG_BASE_PORT)
th.start()

while True:
    try:
        sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

th.running = False
th.join()
```

QThread subscriber code that breaks at random:

```
class ZmqListener(QtCore.QThread):

    message = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__(self, addr, port, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.addr = addr
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        socket = zmq.Context().socket(zmq.SUB)
        socket.connect("tcp://%s:%s" % (self.addr, self.port))
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "{}:".format(IMG_SUBS_HEAD).encode('utf-8'))
        poller = zmq.Poller()
        poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            s = dict(poller.poll(1000))
            if s:
                if s.get(socket) == zmq.POLLIN:
                    msg = socket.recv()
                    self.message.emit(msg[len(IMG_SUBS_HEAD)+1::])
        socket.close()
```

publisher code:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ios>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#define PORT 13600
#define PUBS "test:"
#define NBYT 256 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024

int main()
{
  zmq::context_t context(1);
  zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
  std::string rep_head;
  char bytes[NBYT];

  std::string zaddr("tcp://*:");
  zaddr += std::to_string(PORT);
  socket.bind(zaddr.c_str());

  rep_head = std::string(PUBS);

  int idx = 0;
  while (1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NBYT; i++)
      bytes[i] = rand();   // sleazy                                                                            
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << rep_head << std::hex << (int)idx << ":";
    zmq::message_t msg(ss.str().length() + NBYT);
    memcpy((char*)msg.data(), ss.str().data(), ss.str().length());
    memcpy(((char*)msg.data())+ss.str().length(), bytes, NBYT);
    socket.send(msg);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
  }

  socket.close();

  return 0;
}
```

I've recently updated my OS (Ubuntu 18.04) and this was not a problem in the past.

Comment: Would you mind to respect the MCVE style of the StackOverflow Best Practice? There is neither any **publisher-code**, nor the messages' payload-**sizing** and data in the MCVE, yet, posted, so the problem is not reproducible. Details about python and ZeroMQ **versions** plus the both pub/sub platforms' ( VMs? ) **RAM details** and the copies of the your system already observed ( so far just mentioned ) **error-tracebacks** are missing either. Thanks for your kind reconsideration, @johnnymopo, about posting the completed problem MCVE-formulation.

Comment: I will follow on your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: The python MCVE code is not reproducible as it uses undefined symbols **`IMG_SUBS_HEAD`**, **`IMG_BASE_PORT`**

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Never violate API rules**. *Never worth trying to do that*

**`PUB`** side ought follow the ZeroMQ API documentation: never access messages data "manually", always use `{ zmq_msg_init() | zmq_msg_init_data() | zmq_msg_init_size() }`-mutually-exclusive member-functions, without ever touching the fragile eggs directly ( content referenced by the pointers )

```
void myFuncToFREE ( void *data2FREE, void *hint ) // UTILITY FUN FOR FREE-ING MEMORY 
{                                                 //                 STRAIGHT ON .SEND()
     free ( data2FREE );
}


    ...
    zmq_msg_t message;
    int       message_len = ss.str().length() + NBYT;
 // int  zmq_msg_init_data ( zmq_msg_t *msg, void *data, size_t size, zmq_free_fun *ffn, void *hint );
    rc = zmq_msg_init_data ( &message,  // -------------- LOAD AT ONCE:
                           < here put concatenated both ss.str().data() + bytes >,
                             message_len,
                             myFuncToFREE,
                             NULL
                             );
   assert ( rc == 0 && "INF: FAILED call to zmq_msg_init_data() ... " );
   ...

   rc = zmq_msg_send( &message, socket, 0 );
   assert ( rc == message_len && "INF: FAILED call to zmq_msg_send() ... " );
   ...

   rc = zmq_msg_close( &message ); // Note that this is NOT necessary after a successful zmq_msg_send()
   assert ( rc == 0 && "INF: FAILED call to zmq_msg_close() ... " );
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I had had successes using the example here:

Comment: Do you think this would make a difference on subscriber side?  Not running in a QTgread seems to make a difference